# How to use custom activation on a custom keras layer

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I want to create a **gaussian activation function** where I want to train the **mean** and **standard deviation**. So, using a custom layer, I've returned the **mean** and **std**, but then unable to extract the learned parameters and feed to activation unit.

class MyLayer(Layer):

```
def __init__(self, output_dim,m,st, **kwargs):
    self.units = output_dim
    self.m=m
    self.st=st
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                          initializer='uniform',
                                          trainable=True)
    self.m = self.add_weight(name='mean',
                                      shape=(1, 1),
                                          initializer='uniform',
                                          trainable=True)
    self.std = self.add_weight(name='std',
                                      shape=(1, 1),
                                          initializer='uniform',
                                          trainable=True)


    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

def call(self, x):
    return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim,m,std)
```

How to use a custom activation function along with this custom layer

Comment: Show us your code